# What is the starting vector $x_1$ for construction of symmetric tridiagonal matrix using Lanczos algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

From what I know the Lanczos algorithm takes a symmetric matrix $A$ and a vector $v$ of norm $1$ as inputs, then generates tridiagonal matrix $J$ and orthonormal matrix $V$ such that $J = V^TAV$. I read the paper [A Survey of Matrix Inverse Eigenvalue Problems](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c520/40e487db1242bd77b7c27ec0d81e50ba8e78.pdf) By Boley and Golub (1986) that makes me confused.

In this paper having constructed a bordered diagonal matrix $B$ (a matrix whose graph is a star graph) using values $\lambda=\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots, \lambda_n\}$ and $\mu=\{\mu_1, \mu_2, \cdots, \mu_{n-1}\}$ eigen data such that $\sigma(B)=\lambda$ and $\sigma(B_1)=\mu$ where $B_1$ is the matrix $B$ after removing its first row and column and 
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
a1&b^T\\b&M
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
a1&b_1&b_2& \dots&b_{n-1}\\
b_1&\mu_1&0&\cdots&0\\
b_2&0&\mu_2&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\\
b_{n-1}&0&0&\cdots&\mu_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
it constructs tridiagonal matrix $J$ such that $\sigma(J)=\lambda$ and $\sigma(J_1) = \mu$ in the following way:

Using the orthogonal tranformation (Householder) we have

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&Q_1^T
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&b_1e_1^T\\b_1e_1&J_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&Q_1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1&b^T\\b&M
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It is clear the above transformation keeps the eigenvalues of $B$ and $B_1$. On carrying out the multiplication, we find

$$
Q_1^TJ_1Q_1 = M, Q_1b_1e_1 = b
$$
The first equation shows that the eigenvectors of $J_1$ are the columns of $Q_1$ and the second equation shows that, apart from the factor $b_1$, the vector $b$ is the vector of first components of the eigenvectors of $J_1$:
$$
b = b_1\{q_{11}, q_{12}, \cdots, q_{1, n-1}\}
$$

This is what I can't understand

> Thus, apart from the factor $b_1$, $b$ is the vector $v$ needed for the construction of $J_1$ from the Lanczos algorithm.

It is clear the method first builds a bordered diagonal matrix in some way, then uses the $b$ as the starting vector. If the Lanczos algorithm works by any starting vector with norm $1$, then why it tries to build this using the $b$ vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting vectors in most of the eigenvalue algorithms are initialized with a random vector with entries $X \sim N(0,1)$ If you look in Trefethen. You should note that they randomly initialize most of the algorithms in numerical linear algebra.

[image]

It says "arbitrary" but what it means it is random. Some code follows after an explanation. The Lanzcos algorithm is in a suite of algorithms called the Krylov methods. The Krylov methods are a specific type of iterative eigenvalue algorithm as opposed to direct methods. The Krylov methods are listed below.

[image]

To explain how Lanczos works I am going to explain how Arnoldi works. The basis of both of these eigenvalue methods is first to use a similarity transform reducing to Hessenberg form. That is the following

$$A = QHQ^{*} $$

or 
$$AQ = QH $$

Instead, we compute $Q_{n} $ letting it be a $m \times n$ matrix whose first $n$ columns are of $Q$

Additionally, we have[image]

In the book it calls it Hessenberg matrix however my professor said it is "hessenbergish".  We end up with

$$ A Q_{n} = Q_{n+1} \bar{H_{n+1}} $$

The idea is simple that we are actually building Krylov subspaces

$$ \mathbf{K_{n}} = \langle b, Ab, \cdots, A^{n-1}b \rangle = \langle q_{1} ,q_{2} , \cdots q_{n} \rangle $$

We form these throught the QR decomp

$$ K_{n} = Q_{n}R_{n}$$

Now the we had $H_{n+1}$ to remove this row we note the following. $ Q_{n}^{*}Q_{n+1}$ is the  $n \times (n+1)$ identity then $Q_{n}^{*}Q_{n+1}\bar{H_{n}}$ is $ n \times n$ Hessenberg matrix obtained by removing the last row.

$$ H_{n} = Q_{n}^{*}AQ_{n} $$

Now if you see we are iteratively building our projections through these Krylov subspaces.

The Lanczos iteration is simply when the matrix is symmetric.

```
function [T varargout] = myLanczos(mat,varargin)
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Syntax:       T = myLanczos(mat);
%               T = myLanczos(mat,k);
%               T = myLanczos(mat,v);
%               T = myLanczos(mat,k,v);
%               [T Q] = myLanczos(mat);
%               [T Q] = myLanczos(mat,k);
%               [T Q] = myLanczos(mat,v);
%               [T Q] = myLanczos(mat,k,v);
%               
% Inputs:       mat is a symmetric or Hermitian N x N matrix
%
%               k is the number of Lanczos iterations to perform. The
%               default value is N
%
%               v is an N x 1 vector (internally forced to have unit norm)
%               specifying a particular starting vector to use. The default
%               vector is chosen uniformly at random from the unit sphere
%
% Outputs:      T is a k x k symmetric tridiagonal matrix. When k < N, T is
%               approximately similar to mat up to rank k. When k = N, T is
%               similar (in the linear algebra sense) to mat. That is, when
%               k = N, T has identical eigenvalues to mat
%
%               Q is the N x k similarity transformation such that
%               mat = Q * T * Q'. Note that equality holds only when k = N.
%               For k < N, mat ~ Q * T * Q'
%
% Description:  This function uses the Lanczos algorithm with full
%               reorthogonalization to compute k x k symmetric tridiagonal
%               matrix T that approximates mat up to rank k with respect to
%               transformation Q. That is, mat = Q * T * Q'. Note that
%               equality holds only for k = N. For k < N, mat ~ Q * T * Q'
%
%               NOTE: In particular, when k = N, T has identical
%               eigenvalues to mat
%
% Author:       Brian Moore
%               brimoor@umich.edu
%
% Date:         July 5, 2013
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Knobs
symTol = 1e-8;

% Check input matrix size
[m,n] = size(mat);
if (m ~= n)
    error('Input matrix must be square');
end

% Make sure input matrix is symmetric
if max(max(abs(mat - mat'))) > symTol
    error('Input matrix is not symmetric to working precision');
end

% Parse user inputs
if (nargin == 2)
    if (length(varargin{1}) == n)
        k = n;
        v = varargin{1};
    else
        k = varargin{1};
        v = randn(n,1);
    end
elseif (nargin == 3)
        k = varargin{1};
        v = varargin{2};
else
    k = n;
    v = randn(n,1);
end

% Initialize variables
Q = nan(n,k);
q = v / norm(v);
Q(:,1) = q;
d = nan(k,1);
od = nan(k-1,1);

% Perform Lanczos iterations
for i = 1:k
    z = mat * q;
    d(i) = q' * z;

    %----------------------------------------------
    % Uncomment only one of the following 3 options
    %----------------------------------------------
    % Option 1: Full re-orthogonalization
    %z = z - Q(:,1:i) * (Q(:,1:i)' * z);

    % Option 2: Full re-orthogonalization (x2)
    z = z - Q(:,1:i) * (Q(:,1:i)' * z);
    z = z - Q(:,1:i) * (Q(:,1:i)' * z);

    % Option 3: No re-orthogonalization
    %z = z - d(i) * q;
    %if (i > 1)
    %    z = z - od(i-1) * Q(:,i-1);
    %end
    %----------------------------------------------

    if (i ~= k)
        od(i) = norm(z);
        q = z / od(i);
        Q(:,i + 1) = q;
    end
end

% Construct T
T = diag(d) + diag(od,-1) + diag(od,1);

% Return user-requested information
if (nargout == 2)
    varargout{1} = Q;
end
```

if you note if v is not specified it is these lines

```
else
        k = n;
        v = randn(n,1);
    end

    % Initialize variables
    Q = nan(n,k);
    q = v / norm(v);
```

It is constructing an orthogonal eigenvector. $q_{1}$ and each one after that from it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Then why the paper didn't do that? it made lot's of computations to get the initial vector!

Comment: One moment I'll amend this.

Comment: @Drupalist some changes made

Comment: Thanks you for your explanation. So from what I understand it did all the computations to get the orthogonal matrix $Q_1$, right?

Comment: Well, the initial vector $x_{1}$ is just some random unit normal vector. it isn't orthogonal. The preceding steps are attempting to create orthogonal vectors by subtracting off projections using the inner product.